# N-channel MOSFETs won't turn off in H-bridge circuit

Tags: transistors, mosfet, brushless-dc-motor, h-bridge

I am trying to follow this circuit; it is a simple 3-phase H-bridge with three N-channel MOSFETs and three P-channel MOSFETs:

[image]

The problem I am having is when I turn on one of the top (P-channel) MOSFETs and turn on one of the bottom (N-channel) MOSFETs, current continues to flow through all three of the N-channel MOSFETs even though two of them should be turned off.

The full amount of current flows through the upper MOSFET, but for some reason when it comes back out of the motor it keeps getting split between the bottom MOSFETs.

I know for a fact that my circuit is set up correctly (according to this circuit) and I am turning off two N-channel MOSFETs while keeping one on, but for some reason current continues to flow through the MOSFETs that should be off. I have tried rebuilding the circuit 3 times and I got the same result all 3 times.

Is there a reason why these MOSFETs won't turn off when they are supposed to be off?

Comment: You can't PWM with pull-up resistors. Too slow. Which can burn out your MOSFETs at which point they fail short.

Comment: I'm guessing the problem is that you are not sending the correct signal states because the logic scheme of your circuit is unusual and not consistent throughout the circuit. But you have not told us what signals states you are sending to cause your PMOS and NMOSs to conduct or not conduct.

Comment: @DKNguyen So I rebuilt it just using the P channel and N channel mosfets hooked up to the motor with a pull down resistor. So i got rid of the bjt transistors. I hooked up 1 N channel mosfet gate to positive, and the rest to negative. Then I hooked 1 P channel mosfet gate to negative, and the other 2 to positive. Is that correct?

Comment: That is correct. Now tell me what you expect the PMOS and NMOS to do when you send a 'HI' or 'LO' to the associated *gate drive* circuitry.

Comment: I send a High signal to 1 N channel mosfet and the other 2 are are Low. I then send a Low signal to 1 P channel mosfet and the other 2 are High. I expect that this would turn on the one N channel mosfet and one P channel mosfet which allows current to flow.

Comment: ...shoot haha. Well what should I do instead? Keep in mind I pulled out the BJT transistors so i'm just driving a mosfet directly in my new circuit

Comment: The "I send a high signal to 1 N channel" is without BJT transistors. I took them out to simplify the circuit

Comment: Then that is correct. With BJTs: Sending a LO to the PMOS's BJT produces a LO on the PMOS gate which causes it to conduct, otherwise the pullup resistor keeps the PMOS not conducting. The pullup resistor keeps the NMOS conducting by default and sending a HI to the NMOS's BJT causes it to stop conducting. What your description does is cause two PMOS to conduct and two NMOS to conduct.

Comment: Another potential problem is that PMOS and NMOS of that schematic are not logic level. They all require at least |Vgs| of 10V to conduct. If your Vcc is not at least 10V things aren't going to work properly. When using MOSFETs as a switch you want a Vgs at least that which is listed to achieve the rated RDson. Ignore Vgs_threshold. That's for when the MOSFET barely starts conducting. Not useful when using as a switch. Is only relevant when using as an amplifier.

Comment: Well i'm an idiot lmao. Turns out I just checked the part numbers and I was using an IRF3205 which I thought was a p channel mosfet, but it's actually an N channel mosfet.

Comment: Yep, that will do it. But now you need a floating high-side gate drive if you want to use NMOS on the high-side.

Comment: Yeah I should be able to do that. I was researching that earlier today. But what would you recommend I do if I want to PWM since the resistor is too slow?

Comment: Floating gate drive aside, pull the gate up with a NPN and pull the gate down with a PNP. You are basically replacing the pull resistor with a transistor. But you use a NPN to pull-up and PNP to pull-down so you can drive both BJTs off the same signal without shoot-through. They are emitter followers so are work more like amplifiers here rather than switches so won't pull as close to the rails as if you had NPN on the bottom and PNP on top but the problem there is shoot-through which is just more circuitry to deal with.

Comment: Oh yeah that makes sense. I think I got it from here. Thanks again!

Comment: Was editing comment. Make sure you read the updated one.

Answer (score 1):

From the comments above it seems your main question was answered by the realization that the upper devices were NMOS and not PMOS. But you also had a question about how best to drive these devices. If you will be using a 5 VDC supply and drive signals, it might be possible to drive the gates directly or through a small resistor, assuming you will use both NMOS and PMOS devices. This depends largely on the switching times required as well as the gate characteristics and motor drive requirements.

It is usually best to use gate driver ICs which can provide high current for fast switching, and half-bridge drivers can incorporate a bootstrap circuit which provides a floating power supply for high side NMOS devices. But you can make a simple and inexpensive gate driver using NPN and PNP transistors. I made a simulation showing how two such drivers can be used to drive a PMOS and NMOS device in a half-bridge configuration. You do need to provide proper pulse dead time to avoid shoot-through. Many driver ICs have dead time and cross-conduction safeguards built in.

[image: MOSFET driver simulation]

There is only 200 nSec dead time in this simulation so some shoot-through can be seen.